# view partial update query in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to show the partial update query generated by a user...in the view.

To save an attribute, I use this..

```
@pin.update_attributes(params[:pin])
```

I can see that the update query when through in the terminal...and only updated the checkbox which changed (which is correct)

```
UPDATE "pins" SET "rose" = 't', "updated_at" = '2012-06-01 16:51:51.942695' WHERE "pins"."id" = 41
```

Is there a method to display this line in the view though?  I tried just using @pin.update_attributes(params[:pin]).to_s, but that didn't pull the query above (just said true).

Thank you.

Thank you.

Comment: Does @pin.update_attributes(params[:pin]).to_sql work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your code around a bit:

```
@pin.attributes = params[:pin]   # Will not save the @pin object
@changes = @pin.changed          # Contains the attributes that have been changed
@pin.save                        # Saves the changes
```

Answer (score 2):

Ty this

```
@pin.update_attributes(params[:pin]).to_sql
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: "NoMethodError (undefined method `to_sql' for true:TrueClass)".

Comment: I would settle for just being able to find the params that are updated.  i.e. params[:pin] shows the parameters submitted...but I just want to see the parameters that change...Rails is clearly making a partial query, but I can't find out how to get those parameters...